# How To Hide Mounted Drives From Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

After scrolling with the mouse while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Nautilus, my icons for mounted hard drives have increased to the maximum size. (They are parallel to the thumbnails' view size, which looks like a bug to me. The size remains after a restart.) Anyway, I'd like to hide them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 18):

Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible 'false'
```

Alternatively, if you have **(GNOME) Tweaks** installed, you can use it to disable '*Mounted Volumes*' under **Desktop**:

[image]

---

This **won't work for Ubuntu 19.04 and later** as desktop icons are handled by a GNOME Shell extension instead of Nautilus for those releases.

Comment: the command just works like charm

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, this won't work for Ubuntu 19.04 and later as desktop icons are handled by a GNOME Shell extension instead of Nautilus for those releases.

Comment: What is yout theme?

Comment: @e-info128 I don't remember exactly, the screenshot is much older than the answer. Most probably a forked Arc theme.

Comment: @Kohjah Does it actually have an option to disable drives? Last time I checked (long time ago), it only had enable/disable options for home folder and trash icon. If there is an option for mounted drives now, please post a new answer with details and preferably a screenshot. That would be valuable and much appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: dconf-editor/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/show-mounts ->disable

Comment: @Minhaj The question was about hiding the icons from the **desktop**, not from the **dock** as you suggest.

Answer (score 18):

For Ubuntu 19.10, the following commands does the trick:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04 hide all icons on second screen (if use two screens).

Comment: The question is about hiding the icons from the **desktop**, nothing about the dock. Your answer is suitable for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181799/480481) (which is already answered).

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04 up to Ubuntu 20.10:

1. Open the dconf editor, or if you don't have it installed, install it from the software center
2. Click "org"
3. Click "gnome"
4. Click "shell"
5. Click "extension"
6. Click "desktop icons"

Then, on the window, disable the `show-mount` option, and you are done.

P.S.: If you want to disable the dock mount icon go back and click dash-to-dock option in the extension section of previous step and from there around the bottom disable the show-mount option.

---

Location link is: /org/gnome/shell/extensions/desktop-icons/

Notice: On Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu on wayland: there seems to be no option `show-mount`.

Comment: "then on the window" in step 6 - there is no entry for the mounted drive I'm looking for. I did find the option dash-to-dock but it's called "show-mounts" and applies to ALL mounted drives (which I'd like to keep as icons). Man... Ubuntu. Why are these things so hard?

Comment: well, at least ubuntu( Linux generally) gives you these options to modify these settings and a great community like this will always help you...bruh the more you use Linux the more it became addictive btw.

Comment: I'm all for Linux but it still has to be said that there is room for improvement!

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be useful for people using multiple monitors (tested on two monitors) with Ubuntu 19.10 and above.

Run the following command as mentioned in the other answers,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

After you run this, your entire dock might get hidden in the secondary monitors (will be visible only one of the monitors).

To circumvent this, restart the gnome-shell*.

This can be done by pressing Alt+F2, typing r and hit enter. Once the gnome-shell restarts you should have the dock restored in the other monitors.

*If you're on Wayland, you may need to restart the shell by logging out and logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "Ubuntu Desktop" (is in settings)

There you can click on "Configure dock behavior"
This opens a new window where you can select which drives to show (or hide all)

Answer (score -3):

If you are on Ubuntu 19+:

1) Go to your menu and search for a program called [Desktop Settings] or [Desktop Icons]

[image: screen]

2) Slide mounted drives so it is greyed out

Comment: Is the screenshot actually from a standard Ubuntu 19+ with **GNOME**? Looks like from Linux Mint (Cinnamon?) to me!

Comment: Can not find it!