# How do I hide the icon for a mounted volume from the dock on Ubuntu 19.10 and later?

Tags: mount, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 19.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 19.10. This made that my second internal HDD show up in the launcher bar or Ubuntu Dock, which it did not before.

I read that I should mount it to `/mnt` instead of `/media`, but this device was auto-mounted years ago (I believe in Ubuntu 16.04 or so) and I have a lot of symlinks and other references to the path in `/media` already.

How can I remove the icon from the dock without unmounting it or having to mount it to a different location? I can not even move it to another location on the bar.

Comment: Why not set the location where you want it to be, ie. making an entry for it in your file system table (`/etc/fstab`)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

Comment: I was getting this message `GLib-GIO-Message: 10:56:36.397: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223897/9318372 fixed it.

Comment: @Hyperplane I tried with `sudo` and didn't get it anymore.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 19.10 and using this command returns no errors, but does not remove the icons from the dock.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and tried the above command. It works perfectly. It removed from the dock immediately.

Comment: indeed it is working on ubuntu 19.10. Thank you.

Comment: Running this on 20.04 hides all icons from the dock on secondary displays

Comment: @Eliezer That should not have happened. Please consider reporting a bug at launchpad.net.

Comment: Not working on 20.04

Comment: @pomsky I don t get any message at all when trying `false` or `true`. I tried several times after rebooting

Comment: i@ironzionlion Consider asking a new question (with a link to this question as a reference) with enough technical details about your system and the software and perhaps a screenshot.

Answer (score 10):

In `/etc/fstab` locate the line that mounts your drive and remove `x-gvfs-show`

This can also be done in the `Disks` GUI, select the HDD, choose the options gear and select "Edit Mount Options", specify the options you want and uncheck "Show in user interface"

[image]

This will allow other removable media, like USB sticks and external HDD to show up, but your "permanent" extra drives to be hidden as "normal"

Comment: For `/etc/fstab`, if `x-gvfs-show` is not listed explicitly and the icon is still displayed, then you can also use the option `x-gvfs-hide`.