# New icon for Google Drive locked on the dock after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock, 19.10

I have updated to **Ubuntu 19.10** from CLI and, after the update, I have found a new icon on the dock.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, it is an icon to mount and open the *'GDrive'* cloud service. Anyway, the icon does nothing and it seems irremovable. Also, a right-click on the icon shows an *'Add to Favorites'* option and it makes no sense because the icon is already stable on the dock.

How could I remove that icon from the dock?

Answer (score 13):

Please, try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this and I posted here too, but it removes also the internal drive from the dock.

Comment: The goal is to keep google online accounts with all its features, BUT remove the google drive icon from the dock on the left, especially while the drive is NOT MOUNTED! We would like to keep the mounted drives visible on the dock though.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu Configuration -> online accounts, check your Google account and unmark "Files".

This action will remove that horrible icon from your dock.

Comment: But that would also remove the feature which allows you to access the files in your Google Drive using Nautilus (Files application), right?

Comment: @pomsky correct. thats why this is NOT A SOLUTION for me too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is the right behavior, but the solution to remove internal mounted drive icons from the dock from here ([How do I hide internal drive from Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181799/how-do-i-hide-internal-drive-from-ubuntu-dock)) works.

If someone has a better solution, perhaps it removes the icon of the remote unit but still allows to show the internal units, it should write it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove your google account from the online accounts in gnome settings. This will prevent creation of the icon in the dock.

But if you use any other Google stuff (like gmail, chrome, calendar etc.), you will not be automatically logged in when you want to use that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can manually allow or deny integration of your Google account to various services by Google (like this: https://www.ubuntupit.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/GNOME-Online-Accounts.png). So you can also allow Google account access for other stuffs (mail, contacts, calendar etc.) and deny for Drive.

Comment: ^[Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183696/480481) is posted related to my comment above.