# Remove system folders from Ubuntu Dock and Nautilus

Tags: mount, directory, 20.04, ubuntu-dock

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 a few days ago. After 2 or 3 days with no reason the icons of two directories appear on my application panel as mounted volumes (screenshot below): root directory `/` and efi `/boot/efi`.

[image: Screenshot 1]

There are only 3 different operations that I can apply to these folders: "New window", "Run using a discrete graphics card" and "Unmount".

They also become visible in Nautilus as mounted volumes (screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot 2]

How is it possible to remove them from the application panel (Ubuntu Dock)?

**EDIT 1**:
After changing system language to English, folders are disappeared. But what was the problem?

**EDIT 2**:
Also, I found that there was 2 nautilus installed on my PC, maybe it was the main cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem running in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

as advised in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182043/821783).