# How To Show Mounted Drives on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop When Using Nemo as Default

Tags: mount, 20.04, drive, desktop-icons, nemo

I have a mounted drive that I want to show up on my desktop. I know that there is a method [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108204/how-to-hide-mounted-drives-from-ubuntu-18-04-desktop) to do this with Nautilus and 18.04, but I am using Nemo, not Nautilus. I just wanted you to know that this is NOT a duplicate. I have turned the setting `org.nemo.desktop volumes-visible` to `true`, but it doesn't show up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just R.click the desktop -> Desktop Settings. Check Mounted Drives is switched 'On'. Then plug in any external drive and you should see it mount on the desktop. That's all there is to it.

Comment: No, I Only Get (for R.Click Menu: New Folder, Show Desktop in Files, Open in Terminal, Change Background, Display Settings.

Comment: Sounds like you are running Gnome as your desktop manager. I had assumed you were running the Cinnamon DM, as Nemo is the default file manager for Cinnamon. Are you trying to run Gnome as your DM with Nemo as FM?

Comment: @PaulBenson yes i am.